# What is the idea behind SingleOutputStreamOperator extending from DataStream class in Apache Flink?

Tags: apache-flink

I was going through the Apache Flink source code and found that SingleOutputStreamOperator class extends from DataStream class.
From the name itself it looks like an operator, then why instead of extending from StreamOperator it extends from  DataStream class.
What is the motive behind such design ?

Answer (score 4):

`SingleOutputStreamOperator` represents a user defined transformation applied on `DataStream` with one predefined output type. In that sense it is a specialization of the `DataStream` because the result is also a data stream but it is the result of a transformation.

There are also two different subtypes of `DataStream`: the `KeyedStream` which represents a stream for which a key is defined and the `SplitStream` which contains multiple split streams from which you can select.